# How is it possible to make an Underline fadeIn with Jquery? (Background-Image?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, css-transitions

I have a menu. With jQuery I manage to underline a menu item on .mouseenter. 
Here is my Fiddle on it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass('script');
   });

    $('a').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('script');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Home</a>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Not Home</a>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Far Away</a>
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">My Son</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MSdzp/

I am using a background image, because I like the underlining to be red. But I would like it to fadeIn and fadeOut, instead of just appearing on .mouseenter. If I am using the duration, it just waits some time before just appearing.

Is it possible to make the underlining of an menu item fadeIn on mouseenter with jQuery? or jQueryUI?

I througoutly searched the web, but couldn't find a solution to this yet. First time posting here.

Comment: `</li>` are also needed, hope it's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would work with a border bottom in stead of a image, and work with css transitions to fade it in. The css would look like this:

```
#menu li a {
    color: #EAEAEA;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: border-color .5s;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:#FFF;
    border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    // transition: border-color .5s; // edit: not required, credits to @RokoC.Buljan
}
```

I update your fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/MSdzp/1/

Comment: the second `transition: border-color .5s;` is not needed. `°!°`

Comment: @RokoCBuljan I assumed that if he wanted the line to fade in, he would also want it to fade out, so that is why I added the second transition. Perhaps I assumed wrong...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan turns out you are right. If you add the transition to the default style only it will work in both directions, if you add it to the :hover style it will only work on mouse in. Thanks, I learned something new today!

Comment: (That's what's the easing for, you have different types, otherwise you can always use CSS3 `animation`) You're always welcome :)

Comment: I use this technique all the time. Unfortunately, if you wanted to use it for text links, you'd have to make sure there's no word-wrapping involved.

Answer (score 3):

No image needed at all! http://jsbin.com/atiyew/1/edit

```
#menu li a {
    color: #EAEAEA;
    /*display:block;*/
    display:inline; /* added */
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:3px solid transparent; /* added */
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s; /* added */
            transition: 0.6s; /* added */
}
#menu li:hover a { /* added */
    border-bottom:3px solid red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to have a css class which has the underline styles, with css transitions* enabled on the element which is going to be underlined. Then use jQuery toggleClass() to add/ remove this underline class. You don't need to use an image, it will load faster without. This is the easy way to enable all transitions, but 'tis better to only use only the rules you need to transition.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
```